# Im being hacked by someone who created a VPN and set up a hotpot on my phone

Tags: attacks, vpn, hotspot

I know as fact that this guy (who I actually know), set up a VPN on my phone that I cant find but can access the logs created by it. He has hijacked all of my email accts, and my Google acct.

Every time I change a password he goes and changes it again. I believe he has accessed my cam and mic. I've tried a factory reset with no luck. What should I do?

Comment: Attempting a factory reset it was a wise move. However, if you did not succeed yourself, you should bring the phone to a repair service which should be able to do it for you (possibly using lower-level tools if required). Apart from that I don't see any other concrete answer we could bring here.

Comment: What's the story that lead to this? Did the suspect have access to your phone for some time? Why do you know for a fact that this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

If the factory reset does not work, you should assume that the ROM itself got hacked. He probably simply installed a backdoored ROM, cooked to order (I've seen such ROMs made available for children's phones - whatever you do, Mom will still be able to track you and read your chats and emails). So, to all intents and purposes, that is *his* phone, no longer *yours*.

The only thing you can reasonably do is to get the phone to the tech representative and ask for a full ROM restore, mentioning the fact that there's probably an unreliable/hacked loader. This is known as bare-metal restore, or sometimes "unbricking".

While the phone is being serviced, change *all* your passwords. All at the same time. Possibly late at night when he's likely to be asleep. Then turn on two-factor authentication wherever possible, and be sure never to leave the phone in easy reach of anyone.